# Passing data to a slider

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on a prototype for a storefront, and I have a slider where I have the option to see the user's profile. Every user has to register first before they can access the store (is just a prototype).

When a new user registers successfully, they will be immediately sent to the product catalog screen. On the same catalog there will be a slider, and in that slider there will be an option to see the user's profile page.

My question is, how can I send the user's info (name, email and phone number) through the catalog page, then trough the slider, and then to the user's profile page?

I already have a class that holds the user's info that's created on the RegisterPage class/screen.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm reading the question wrong, it sounds like some kind of state management solution would be useful here. That is, once you know the user's details, they should be stored in a place that is easily accessible later on from other widgets.

There are a few state management options available:

- [`StatefulWidget`](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive) - a classic, simplest approach. Have a `StatefulWidget` which tracks state (user's details), and pass them down the widget tree to a component that can make use of those details. Gets a little unwieldy if you have a deep tree and need to pass the data down through several layers that don't really care about said data.
- [`InheritedWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html). Propagate information down the widget tree and rebuild UI whenever inherited widget itself changes state. Relatively straightforward, simple solution. Unlike `StatefulWidget`, you can retrieve required data where you need it, and you don't have to pass it down as arguments to yet another widget.
- [Provider package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider). A state management solution by Remi Rousselet, endorsed by Google itself. Easy to use and understand, and quite scaleable. Advertised as:

  > A mixture between dependency injection (DI) and state management, built with widgets for widgets.
- [Redux](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_redux). Another state management solution that comes in a form of a package. If you've worked with React/Redux, you will feel right at home. It's not as full-featured as its JavaScript counterpart, but the idea is the same: have a store to which some widgets are listening, and rebuild them whenever data changes.
- [BLoC / Rx](https://medium.com/flutterpub/architecting-your-flutter-project-bd04e144a8f1). One of the Google's recommended ways to manage state. Leans heavily on streams. Is somewhat more complex to understand, but rather powerful once you do.
- [MobX](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx.dart). Another state management solution ported from JavaScript world. I haven't had much experience with it, but I believe it's based on observables, actions and reactions. I expect it should be quite similar to JavaScript's counterpart.

You can read more about each of those by heading over to the dedicated page on the official [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options).

Personally, I'd probably choose something relatively simple first - perhaps `InheritedWidget` or `provider` package. However, it heavily depends on your use case and what programming paradigms you're comfortable with / want to experiment with.